# SavedInstantState created during onSaveInstanceState not restored in onCreate

Tags: android, android-activity

My app an activity (which now a subclass on FragmentActivity, although I don't think that matters), let's call it Activity A.

In it, a button navigates away to (say) Activity B by starting it via Intent using startActivity() with no special flags.

Neither activity has any special flags (SingleTop) etc in the manifest, not calls finish() etc. i.e. nothing unusual.

Activity A's method onSaveInstanceState() get's called and I save some state info.

In Activity B I hit the BACK key and come back to Activity A.

It's onCreate() method is called, but the Bundle of "savedInstanceState" is null, and so I cannot reconstruct the state I had previously saved.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong, and how I can ensure I get the state back.

BTW: On a configuration change (say rotate), it all works fine....

Comment: Starting Activity B  and returning to Activity A should only call Activity A's `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods. Your previous state shouldn't be altered... unless the OS killed A in the background to reclaim memory, but then this would be no different than an orientation change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems strange that `onCreate()` is getting called when you go back to Activity A just by pressing the back key. In general it should just show the existing activity without trying to recreate it. I also think it also strange that `onSaveInstanceState()` is getting called when you start the other activity. In fact, the documentation states that it probably *won't* call `onSaveInstanceState()` when starting Activity B:

> An example: when onPause() is called and not
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is when activity B is launched in front of
>   activity A: the system may avoid calling onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)
>   on activity A if it isn't killed during the lifetime of B since the
>   state of the user interface of A will stay intact.

From [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).

I think something else is going on.

Comment: Yes, I also couldn't understand that onCreate() was being called again and you confirmed it....so I investigated....turns out, unbeknownst-to-me, the Activity B was capturing the BACK key and starting a new instance of Activity A (a long story as to why it does that.....). FIXED, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Activity A was never destroyed, therefore onCreate() should not be called. Can you please put some code up?